# How to Iterate a list sent from React in Django

Tags: django

I want to iterate colors in Django, it should print first red then green

```
# data from frontend react
  data = request.data
  print(data)

 <QueryDict: {'colors': ['red', 'green']}>
```

result should be like this :

```
 red
green
```

Comment: `data.getlist('colors')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`.getlist(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to access the list of values, so:

```
>>> print(data.getlist('colors'))
['red', 'green']
```